# meaning of "love of something"

Tags: grammar, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

I am given a sentence "All human love is based on **love of God**".
What does "love of God" mean? Does it mean "human love for God"? or does it mean "God's love for human"? or does it mean something else?

I am confused...

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I admit, I am not sure. But I think it means "human love for God". The main reason I prefer this over "God's love for humans" is because, if the author meant "God's love for human, than I think he/she would have written

> All human love is based on God's love.

To me this sounds natural and has the exact meaning "God's love for humans".

---

***Addendum:***

I realized

> love of (noun)

is a commonly used construction. It means the love a person has for (noun).
For example,

> My love of math drove me to become a math major.

So I think the meaning above is "human love for God". If the author meant "God's love for humans", than another way he or she could have expressed it is as

> All human love is based on love **from** God.

Comment: I think context can shed light on the dilemma! I think previous lines or sentences can be very helpful in this case

Comment: True! I didn't think of that. I took it as a stand alone sentence, like something from a workbook because OP wrote "I am given a sentence".

Comment: +1 to the answer. A native English speaker who wanted to say that human love was based on divine love would say "on God's love" not "on love of God".  "of" in "on love of God" is not the possessive.

Comment: @TRomano BTW comment. It is interesting that we can say human love, **noun** + **noun**, but in the case of god we must use possessive form ?

Comment: @TRomano Yes, I haven't heard "on God's love" in a while, but I agree.

Comment: @Cardinal: do you mean we cannot use "God" adjectivally?  It's because "God" is a name.

Comment: @TRomano Exactly. yes for example, god love

Comment: We could probably get away with "god love".   *Helen of Troy was the result of god love.*  But "God" with a capital G is a name.

Answer (score 0):

JDneverSleeps, I try to do my best:

I think that "**God's Love for Mankind**" is *grammatically correct*.

So long,
Jack

Comment: That's not what the poster was asking, though.

Comment: Sorry, dude. "Wrong forum?!" is more suitable perhaps?English language learners prefers to have no postion in favor of, either than "telling the truth"?!

Comment: Go further and "ask it to a Priest!" I have already seen the Light...

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, "love for" is closer to an enjoinment whereas "love of" - to a passion. Again, my humble opinion.

May "love of" in the example act both ways - as God's love of humans and humans' love of God as an example of how humans should love each other?